# Filter from web.xml is not executed after migration of Spring Security

Tags: servlets, spring-security, servlet-filters

I have several filter defined in my web.xml file. The problem is that after I migrated from Spring Security 3.0.5 to 3.2.5, filters declared after Spring's DelegatingFilterProxy are not executed.

```
...
<filter>
    <filter-name>noCacheHeaderFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.domain.web.filter.NoCacheHeaderFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter>
<filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<!-- not executed bellow ->
<filter>   
    <filter-name>traceFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.domain.web.filter.TraceFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
...
```

Here's the Security config file:

```
<http auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="false">
    <intercept-url pattern="/server/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/includes/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <!--    may be needed later <intercept-url pattern="/static/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>-->
    <intercept-url pattern="/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/error.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/index.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/users/password" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" method="PUT"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/test.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/Silverlight.js" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/ClientBin/**/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/help/**/*" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/components/download/**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>
    <custom-filter ref="unsuccessfulBasicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER"/>
    <!--http-basic /-->
    <form-login login-processing-url="/login"
                authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandlerService"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="loginSuccessHandler"/>
    <logout logout-url="/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"/>

</http>
```

This error happens on "*/login" url. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

That's the code for loginSuccessHandler:

```
@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication != null) {
        String redirectUrl = "";
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session != null) {
            SavedRequest savedRequest = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_SAVED_REQUEST_KEY");
            if (savedRequest != null) {
                redirectUrl = savedRequest.getRedirectUrl();
            }
        }

        User user = ((NgnmsUserDetails)(authentication.getPrincipal())).getUser();
        //if status user, do not add an event (status user is used by status script, to check if NMS is available)
        if(user != null && !user.getLogin().equals(User.STATUS_USER)) { 
            WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
            user.setSessionId(details.getSessionId());
            userService.updateUser(user);
            if (redirectUrl == null || !redirectUrl.contains("/ws/")){
                User.setCurrent(user);
                threadedApplicationEventPublisher.publishEvent(new UserLoginPostEvent(this, user, request.getRemoteAddr()));
            }
        }
    }
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
}
```

In debug this code returns without any problems, however no other filter from spring security's own chain after UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is not called.

Here are debug output from spring security:

```
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,357 DEBUG [FilterChainProxy:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] /login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,358 DEBUG [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] No HttpSession currently exists
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,368 DEBUG [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,370 DEBUG [FilterChainProxy:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] /login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,370 DEBUG [FilterChainProxy:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] /login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,371 DEBUG [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] Request is to process authentication
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,372 DEBUG [ProviderManager:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] Authentication attempt using com.domain.security.impl.springsecurity.RandTechAuthenticationProvider
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,405 DEBUG [CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionFixationProtectionStrategy@5259817a
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,406 DEBUG [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@365ec150: Principal: com.domain.security.impl.springsecurity.NgnmsUserDetails@72439ad2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@59b2: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.143.119; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,429 DEBUG [root:main] preRegister called. Server=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer@149ee0f1, name=log4j:logger=root
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,501 DEBUG [DefaultRedirectStrategy:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] Redirecting to '/index.html'
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,502 DEBUG [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] HttpSession being created as SecurityContext is non-default
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,505 DEBUG [HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@365ec150: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@365ec150: Principal: com.domain.security.impl.springsecurity.NgnmsUserDetails@72439ad2; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@59b2: RemoteIpAddress: 192.168.143.119; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
24-Dec-2014 12:43:23,505 DEBUG [SecurityContextPersistenceFilter:http-192.168.143.119-8090-1] SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds normal. After processing the `login` request, Spring Security will call your `loginSuccessHandler`, which usually does a redirect and returns. Nothing in the filter chain beyond the authentication filter will be invoked (including other filters in your `web.xml`).

Comment: If there was a redirect, then I don't believe it would have. However it's hard to say for sure what's happening without more information, such as what happens in the debug log when you successfully log in and what the code for your `loginSuccessHandler` actually does.

Comment: Again, this looks just as I'd expect. The user is redirected to "/index.html" immediately after logging in (by the call to `super.onAuthenticationSuccess`). The remainder of the filter chain [isn't invoked for an authentication request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java#L220).